# Tab changing in TextMate when working with LaTeX files?

Tags: keyboard, textmate

I tried the new version of TextMate (1.5.10, r1616). I noticed that there's a 'Changed' item on the Release notes stating that the keyboard shortcuts to change tabs are now the de facto standand <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>.

Now, whenever I have a tab with `.tex` file open and I try to browse through tabs TextMate executes Insert commands 'Command Based on Current Word' (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>}</kbd>) and 'Environment Based on Current Word' (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>{</kbd>) from the LaTeX bundle when changing to the next and previous tab, respectively.

So, what are my options to get the situation back to normal? I think I could disable the aforementioned commands from LaTeX bundle with the Bundle Editor, but with a quick look I didn't find them. Are there any other file types beside LaTeX that might cause problems with overlapping shortcuts? Is this overlapping of shortcuts a bug in TextMate? I guess there's no way to change the next/previous tab navigation commands. One obvious solution would be not to update to the latest version.

Comment: You might have some better luck asking at tex.se: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In moments, this update was driving me crazy. Luckily, I remembered that the Mac OS lets you customize keyboard shortcuts. So, I opened system preferences > keyboard > keyboard shortcuts --- and restored my textmate tab navigation to how they were previously! Yay!